# Python code that creates list of prime numbers

Tags: python, primes

Trying to create a list of prime numbers in a fixed range. This is producing non-sensical list but the code makes sense to me.

```
  for number in range(2,100,2):
    k = 1
    while k*k < number:
        k += 2
        if number % k == 0:
           break
    else:
        print(number)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Can you please [edit] your question and add what happens when you run it and what you expected to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask]

Comment: just the first result from google...https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/prime-numbers-using-python-824ff4b3ea19

Comment: First problem I see: You don't test the case of k=2, so you will accept many even numbers as prime.

Comment: Lots of issues here. Glaring, to me at least, is your loop: `for number in range(2,100,2)` `number` in this instance will never be prime since you only test even numbers.

Answer (score 3):

there are several bugs in your code.
first, you don't check its divisibility by even numbers, any even number to be exact (including 2)! if it is meant as an optimization approach, make it more generic by not checking the numbers who are known already not to be prime. its called [the sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
another, is that you don't check the divisibility if n is a square root of a prime number as you pass the k*k = number case.
this is my implementation for a naive n * sqrt(n):

```py
for number in range(2,100):
    prime, divisor = True, 2

    while prime and divisor ** 2 <= number:
        if number % divisor == 0:
            prime = False
        divisor += 1
    
    if (prime):
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change like this:

```
for number in range(2, 101):
   for k in range(2, number):
       if (number % k) == 0:
           break
   else:
       print(number)
```

Comment: Please edit to elaborate on what was wrong with the OP's attempt and how this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in range(1,100):
counter=0
for test in range(1,number+1):
    if number%test==0:
        counter=counter+1
if counter<=2:
    print(number)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is a good answer?

Comment: @ggorlen prime number means it can be divided by itself and 1 so we count the numbers that divide each number we iritate over and if the counter is 2 then it's a prime number

Comment: Please [edit] your explanation into the question and explain why this solution is preferable to the existing answers.